# What is the cause of the “No Data” error when backtesting in Trading View a strategy written in Pine Script? Using MA60

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

Im currently getting the no data error. Can someone please help me decipher the problem with my code?

```
//@version=5
strategy("My script",overlay=true)

ma60 = ta.sma(close,60)



price=close

_color = if ma60 > ma60[1]
color.green
else
    color.red


plot(ma60,color = _color,linewidth = 2)
plot(ma200,color = color.orange, linewidth=3)



//long

if price>ma60 and price> ta.highest(20)
    strategy.entry("longposition",strategy.long,comment="Long Entry")
if price<ma60
     strategy.close("longposition",comment = "long Exit")


//short

if price<ma60 and price< ta.lowest(20)
    strategy.entry("shortposition",strategy.short,comment="Long Entry")
if price<ma60
    strategy.close("shortposition",comment = "long Exit")

//sl

strategy.exit("Exit long sl",from_entry = "longposition",stop=low )

strategy.exit("Exit short sl",from_entry = "shortposition",stop=high )
```

The strategy goes long when price crosses MA60 and close price was the highest price among the recent 20 bars and closes when price come back to MA60.`

Answer (score 0):

`ta.highest(20)` will count the current bar also and `price> ta.highest(20)` can never be `true`.

What you want to have is `price> ta.highest(20)[1]`.